# Is it safe to call a script onunload() using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a webpage where I am displaying 5 puzzles to the user.When the user clicks for next 5 puzzles,I am sending the score of the current page `onunload()` using `AJAX` to the scipt `updateScore.php` to make updations in their account.

I wanted to ask whether it is safe to make such calls `onunload()`? I read somewhere that in some cases the calls may not be sent because you have very less time on unload,hence the request may be missed.Is it true?

Or can you suggest a better method or time to make updations